# How to synchronize operations on Ionic/Angular Storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, storage

Consider the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {

  private _storage: Storage | null = null;

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {
    const storage = await this.storage.create();
    this._storage = storage;
  }

  public setSessionInfo(uid:string, accesToken:string, refreshToken:string){
    this.set('uid',uid);
    this.set('accessToken',accesToken);
    this.set('refreshToken',refreshToken);
  }

  public set(key: string, value: any) {
    this._storage?.set(key, value);
  }

  public async get(key: string){
    let value= await this._storage?.get(key);
    console.log("El valor asociado a la llave es "+value);
    return value;
  }

  public removeSessionInfo(){
    this.remove('uid');
    this.remove('accessToken');
    this.remove('refreshToken');
  }

  public async remove(key: string){
    console.log("Intenta remover el registro "+ key);
    await this._storage?.remove(key);
  }
}
```

Now consider the following TS Component Code:

```
async completePhoneAuthentication(){
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Cargando...',
      cssClass: 'custom-loading'
    });
    let userInfo=await this.authService.verifyOtp(this.otpForm.get('otpCode')?.value,loading);
    console.log("User Info");
    console.log(userInfo);

    if(userInfo){
      let accessToken= await userInfo.user.getIdToken();
      this.storageService.setSessionInfo(userInfo.user.uid,accessToken,userInfo.user.refreshToken);
      this.isCodeFailed = false;
      this.storageService.removeSessionInfo();
      //this.router.navigate(['/main']);
    }
    else{
      this.isCodeFailed = true;
    }
   }

   async removeSessionInfo2(){
    this.storageService.removeSessionInfo();
   }
```

When I call the completePhoneAuthentication() Method the I get the following result on storage:

[image]

According to the logic of the completePhoneAuthentication method, the storage have to be empty, because firts the setSessionInfo method save the values (uid,accessToken and refreshToken) and then removeSessionInfo method delete the info, but the result is that the values ​​remain saved in storage. However, if I call the removeSessionInfo2 method from UI (`<ion-button (click)="removeSessionInfo()">DeleteLocalStorage</ion-button>`)effectively deletes stored information:

[image]

However, If I use the following method the application works as I expected. From what I see, it's a timing problem:

```
async completePhoneAuthentication() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Cargando...',
      cssClass: 'custom-loading'
    });

    let userInfo = await this.authService.verifyOtp(this.otpForm.get('otpCode')?.value, loading);
    console.log("User Info");
    console.log(userInfo);

    if (userInfo) {
      let accessToken = await userInfo.user.getIdToken();
      this.storageService.setSessionInfo(userInfo.user.uid, accessToken, userInfo.user.refreshToken);
      this.isCodeFailed = false;

      // Agregar un retraso de 3 segundos después de this.isCodeFailed = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.storageService.get("uid").then(r => {
          console.log("Se obtiene UID " + r);
        });
        this.storageService.removeSessionInfo();
        this.router.navigate(['/main']);
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      this.isCodeFailed = true;
    }
  }
```

Now the question is how to make the removeSessionInfo method execute only when setSessionInfo has finished executing without having to use setTimeout